# How to animate AnimatedAlign by Curve in Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter

I want bubble to move smoothly between edges of the screen tracking random curves.
This is the code I have

```
class BubbleAnimator extends StatefulWidget {
  const BubbleAnimator({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BubbleAnimatorState createState() => _BubbleAnimatorState();
}

class _BubbleAnimatorState extends State<BubbleAnimator> {
  double x;
  double y;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    x = math.Random().nextDouble()*2-1;
    y = math.Random().nextDouble()*2-1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Bubble(
      x: x,
      y: y,
    );
  }
}

class Bubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final double x;
  final double y;

  const Bubble({Key key, this.x, this.y}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedAlign(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      alignment: Alignment(x, y),
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print("tapped");
          },
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            decoration:
            BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

How could I make my BubbleAnimator to move by curve?

For example, let my bubble shows up in the middle of the screen. Bubble then moves toward random edge of screen by surfing some smooth curve. Hitting the edge bubble then changes it's direction to some other edge tracking another unpredictable curve.

Answer (score 0):

`AnimatedAlign` like any other Animated Widget (`AnimatedContainer`, etc) needs to be inside a `StatefulWidget`.

Your `x` and `y` values can't be `final` as they need to change to animate your `Alignment`.

Either move your `BubbleWidget` logic inside your `BubbleAnimator` or move everything to `Bubble` and convert that one into a `StatefulWidget`.

You'd need to call `setState` every time you change your `x` and `y` variables.